# ¿Como hago para que el saldo final de 0? Tabla de amortizacion en java

Tags: java, matrices, tablas

tengo que hacer una tabla de amortizacion en java usando matrices, para esto tengo que pedir el capital, el numero de periodos y el interes, la idea es rellenar una matriz con los datos de la tabla y luego mostrarla, para comprobar que está bien el saldo final en la ultima fila debe dar cero, pero no consigo hacerlo usando el siguiente ejemplo: periodos: 5, interes: 4, capital: 4. ¿que problema podria tener?
ublic class TablaDeAmortizacion {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner;
    double capital;
    double interes;
    double tasaInteres;
    double cuota;
    int periodos;
    double[][] tabla;
    //instanciacion
    scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Ingrese el capital: ");
    capital = scanner.nextDouble();
    System.out.print("\nIngrese el numero de periodos: ");
    periodos = scanner.nextInt();
    System.out.print("\nIngresa el interes: ");
    interes = scanner.nextDouble();
    tasaInteres = interes / 100;
    System.out.println("interes = " + tasaInteres);

    tabla = new double[periodos][6];
    cuota = (capital * tasaInteres * Math.pow(1 + tasaInteres, periodos))
            / (Math.pow(1 + tasaInteres, periodos) - 1);

    System.out.println("cuota = " + cuota);
    for (int i = 0; i < tabla.length; i++) {
        //periodos
        tabla[i][0] = i + 1;
        //saldo inicial
        if (i == 0) {
            tabla[i][1] = capital;
        } else {
            tabla[i][1] = tabla[i - 1][5];
        }
        //cuota
        tabla[i][2] =cuota;

        //interes50
        tabla[i][3] = tabla[i][1] * tasaInteres;

        //abono a capital
        tabla[i][4] =tabla[i][2] - tabla[i][3];

        //saldo final
        tabla[i][5] = tabla[i][1] - tabla[i][4];

    }
    for (double[] ds : tabla) {
        for (double d : ds) {
            System.out.print(d + "\t");
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }

    System.exit(0);
}
```

}

Comment: "No consigo hacerlo" Qué exactamente? Cuál es el exactamente el error, excepción, problema?

Comment: hola, no da ningun error de codigo, el problema es que en la tabla de amortizacion la ultima fila y ultima columna (saldo final) deberia dar cero para comprobar que si hacen bien los calculos, actualmente si ingreso los datos del ejemplo, el ultimo saldo final da 2 y no 0. no se si me hago entender https://ibb.co/25QKrCn